# Booting from USB on Macbook Pro Mid 2010

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, macbook-pro

I made a bootable USB pendrive with Mac OS X Snow Leopard on it. On my Macbook Pro 2007, this USB pendrive booted and I was able to install Mac OS X from it. I have tried to do the same thing with a Macbook Pro Mid 2010. I powered on the computer, pressed Alt key, selected the pendrive from the Menu but then nothing happened.

Has anyone managed to boot up from a USB pendrive containing Mac OS X ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made the bootable USB from the grey disks that came with your Macbook Pro 2007 then the issue is that those disks have builds that are specific to that model and are never guaranteed to work on other machines.

If you made it with a retail DVD then it should work.  If this is the case try booting into verbose mode and see what you get as the last few output lines.

Comment: I used the retail DVD that came with the laptop. Obviously it worked. I have not tried making a new bootable USB pendrive from the retail DVD.